# How i can see time execute of each function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I receive a project with large code and this project run too slow. My mission is maintenance and update new feature for this project. But when i code on that project, it run too slow.
I need find the code make project run slowly to optimize.
How i can see time execute of each function when run (on development and production environment)?

Edit: more information: this project use more gem to run (I can't show Gemfile for secure)

Comment: This is called profiling. I've had success with `rblineprof`. Check it out.

Comment: Try to use Benchmark module.

Comment: Thank Sergio Tulentsev and user19xxxx, I will try. I had optimize by config and it looklike great.